# "Фильтрованный" поиск

Tags: c#

Есть массив данных то есть строк. Я ввел что софт мне показал, все строки, которые кончаются на `"qj"`, он показал, но потом, надо чтобы софт показал из тех строк, что он нашел, все что кончается, на `"i1"`.Так попроще будет, я думаю...

Типа как-то так:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string readline = Console.ReadLine();
        string st = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        //циклы
        //если строки в массиве кончаются на "qj"
        //console.writeline(строки, которые кончаются на qj);
        //все строки отображаются
        //ввожу еще раз если строки в отобранном массиве кончаются на "i1"
        //софт закончен, коенчная строка найдена..
    }
```

Comment: Как-то очень сумбурно. А вы не можете просто написать, что вам надо, и что у вас получилось, желательно кодом?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov поправил, если совсем так по-тупому написать

Comment: Короче, чтобы просто можно быть бы фильтровать отфильтрованные пункты дальше, вот и вопрос?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov фильтровать отфильтрованные данные столько раз, сколько будет нужно...как-то так

Comment: А как понять когда конец программы и больше фильтровать не нужно?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov 
"когда конец программы и больше фильтровать не нужно?" - больше не нужно, т.к. найден будет конечный результат

Comment: А после второго фильтра не дойдёт ни одна строка, если что, так как строки не могут кончаться и на `qj`, и на `i1`.

Comment: Софт нашел строки, которые кончаются на qj, он их отбразил, потом я ввел еще раз конец строки из тех строк, что она показал, он еще раз изз отсортировал потому чему я ввел, и показал строку, которая будет соответствовать тому что я ввел

Answer (score 1):

Можете использовать такие "строительные блоки" и из них смастерить свою программу:

```
static void Main()
{
    // У вас есть какой-то исходный массив
    string[] array = new[] { "123412qj", "123412", "asdasqj" };

    DisplayStrings(array);
}

static string[] GetFilteredStrings(string[] array)
{
    string filter = Console.ReadLine();

    // Получаем результат
    return array.Where(s => s.EndsWith(filter)).ToArray();
}

static void DisplayStrings(string[] array)
{
    foreach (string s in GetFilteredStrings(array))
        Console.WriteLine(s);        
}
```